# Can IntelliJ 2019 show more than two tool panels stacked on the left?

Tags: intellij-idea, window, panel

On the left side of my IntelliJ window, I can stack two panels, such as `Project` & `Structure`, or `Project` & `Favorites`.

Is there any way to stack all 3 panels atop one another, `Project` & `Structure` & `Favorites`? Or is 2 the maximum?

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to do so, you might consider adding a feature request on JetBrains' tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue .